# Save a RTF / Word as a self contained HTML file

Tags: microsoft-word, html, pictures, rtf

Is there a way to save a Word Document as a **single** HTML file, self contained web page, embedding all the pictures in encode64 or something similar?

When I say, single, it means, as the output, we will have only one single HTML file, opening that file will display our formatted text and embedded pictures, if any.

I need to transform an RTF file to something be able to load in a richTextFormat field in SharePoint... So I need something like

```
this is some <b>bold</b> text and a picture: 
<img src="data:image/png;base64,...>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365 (probably in older versions too) you can save the file as "Single File Web Page" which contain all the images and text. Be aware that complex formatting will be lost when you use this format.

Comment: single file web page is not HTML, I can't use its content to embed in some rich text format field...

Comment: @serge, as it is in the options for save I am 99% sure it can be imported in SharePoint.

Comment: probably it can be imported as a document, but I need html to import it in a SharePoint list fied

Comment: @serge, have you try to import Word document itself? Probably the integration is even better.

Comment: And @serge just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Some manual work needs to be done.

Word can save the document in HTML format, although the generated HTML
is not pretty, is voluminous and is hard to understand.
A third-party utility might do better, but I can't recommend one
from my experience.

To convert an image to its base64 encoding, do the following inside
a Command Prompt (cmd):

```
cd image-folder
certutil -encode mypicture.png mypicture.txt
```

The above will also work for JPEG images.

Open the generated text file in a text-editor, delete the enclosing
lines of "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----",
then join all the lines into a single continuous data-line with no
embedded spaces.

Now open the HTML file in a text-editor, locate the image entry
`<img src="mypicture.png">`, and replace it by:

Conserve other attributes of the `<img>` tag (if any).

For a JPEG image (`.jpg` or `.jpeg`),
use `image/jpeg` instead of `image/png`.

Note that this procedure is only suitable for relatively
small images, and ensure that your text-editor can handle
very long lines.

Comment: let's say, I have some 2000 rtf to transform to html

Comment: You could write a script, in PowerShell or similar, that will automate this work.